# mediaPlayer.getDuration() is not giving correct duration

Tags: android

An audio file playing in desktop apps giving correct duration, but when playing through android using MediaPlayer, the mediaPlayer.getDuration() is giving wrong duration. Please let me know whats the solution for this

Comment: are you calling getDuration after mediaPlayer.OnPreapared()

Comment: Provide more code

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you call `mediaPlayer.getDuration();` after `mediaPlayer.prepare();`